# Discordpy welcome bot

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So, i tried to make a bot that send embed to specific channel everytime user join my server.
The code is look like this

```
import discord
import asyncio
import datetime
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents()
intents.members = True
intents.messages = True
intents.presences = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="a!", intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready.')

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(ctx, member):
    embed = discord.Embed(colour=0x1abc9c, description=f"Welcome {member.name} to {member.guild.name}!")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{member.avatar_url}")
    embed.set_author(name=member.name, icon_url=member.avatar_url)
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    channel = guild.get_channel(816353040482566164)

    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

and i got an error

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Piero\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Piero\Documents\Discord\a-chan\achan_bot\main.py", line 24, in on_member_join
    channel = guild.get_channel(816353040482566164)
NameError: name 'guild' is not defined
```

Anyone know what is wrong in my code?

Comment: You didn't define `guild` anywhere in your code, so how is Python supposed to know what that is?

Comment: I don't think that `ctx` is a parameter which is passed to `on_member_join`. Looking at the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_join), it seems only `member` is passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, looking at the [`discord.py` documention](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_join), `ctx` is not passed to the `on_member_join` event reference. However, you can use the [attributes of `member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member) which *is* passed in order to get the values which you need.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour=0x1abc9c, 
        description=f"Welcome {member.name} to {member.guild.name}!"
    )
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{member.avatar_url}")
    embed.set_author(name=member.name, icon_url=member.avatar_url)
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    channel = member.guild.get_channel(816353040482566164)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Interestingly enough, you did this perfectly for getting the guild name, but it seems you forgot to do the same when retrieving `channel`.

Answer (score 0):

You did not define `guild`.
To define your guild you can do the following:

```py
guild = bot.get_guild(GuildID)
```

It's the same method you used to define your `channel`, just for your `guild` now.

***For further information you can have a look at the docs:*** https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_guild

Also take into account that we do not have a paramter like `ctx` in an `on_member_join` event.
The event  just has the parameter `member` in your case:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member): #Removed ctx
```